# Java Arrays (in a JRE)

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment where I have to set up an array that gets formed by the user (via cmd line), the user determines the length and what numbers are in it. I can't seem to get it to prompt the user at all, but no errors arise when I run it.

This is what I have so far:

```
class hw8064 {
      static void createArray(int x1, int y1){

     int numElements;

     double[] a1;
     a1 = new double[x1];
     double[] a2;
     a2 = new double[y1];
     for (int i=0; i<=a1.length; i++){
         System.out.println("Please enter a double for array 1[<i>] and one for array 2[<i>]:");
     }


     }  
     public static void main(String [] args){
      int numElements;
      if (args.length > 0){
          try{
              numElements = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
          } catch (NumberFormatException e){
              System.out.println("Argument must be an integer");
              System.exit(1);
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

Also I know I need to put something for the arguments when I configure the project file to be able to parse the int in a JRE, but I'm not sure what.
Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:
I have it mostly set up, except for i can't find the variable now...

> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> class hw8064 {
>
> ```
> public static void createArray(double x1, double y1, int numElements) {
>     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>     double a1[] = {x1};
>     a1 = new double[numElements];
>     double a2[] = {y1};
>     a2 = new double[numElements];
>     for (int i = 0; i <= a1.length; i++) {
>         System.out.println("Please enter a double for array 1[<" + i + ">]and one for array 2[<" + i + ">]:");
>
>     }
>
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     if (args.length > 0) {
>
>         try {
>             int numElements = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
>
>         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
>             System.out.println("Argument must be an integer");
>             System.exit(1);
>         }
>         try {
>             int numElements = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
>         } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
>             System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the argument");
>             System.exit(1);
>         }
>
>     }
>     createArray(***numElements***);
> }
> ```
>
> }

the last line where I call the method is giving me problems

Comment: Where do you expect input?

Comment: that is because you are not calling createArray() in main function

Comment: Your code just parses the argument and immediately exits. Use the methods from `System.in` to get user input.

Comment: You said that info will be entered through command line. Will they be your **program parameters** (like your `main()` hints) or **console entries**  while your program already runs (like your `createArray()` tries to do)?

Comment: When the program is executed it will ask the user for 2 integers, and those will determine the length of the two arrays.

Comment: I also anticipate everything to be input into the "output" box in netbeans or eclipse, whatever my professor uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `creatArray` method in your `main` like this

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   int numElements;
   if (args.length > 0){
      try{
          numElements = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e){
          System.out.println("Argument must be an integer");
          System.exit(1);
      }
   }

   createArray(numElements);
}
```

Since you're only getting one argument from the command line, you should only have one parameter for the method

```
 static void createArray(int numElements){
     double[] a1 = new double[x1];

     for (int i=0; i<=a1.length; i++){
         System.out.println(
                   "Please enter a double for array [<" + i + ">] " 
                    + "and one for array 2[<" + i + ">]:");
 }
```

If you want to get two args from the command line, you should do something like this in your `main`

```
if (args.length != 2){
    System.out.println(Usage: numOfElements1 numOfElments2);
    System.exit(0);
} else {
    try {

     } catch ( ..... ) {

     }
}
```

**Edit: complete**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num1;
    int num2;

    if (args.length != 2){
        System.out.println(Usage: numOfElements1 numOfElments2);
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        try {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Arguments must be an integers");
            System.exit(1);  
        }
    }
    createArray(num1, num1);
}

static void createArray(int num`, int num2){
     double[] a1 = new double[num1];
     double[] a2 = new double[num2];

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     for (int i=0; i<=a1.length; i++){
         System.out.println(
                   "Please enter a double for array1[<" + i + ">] ");
         double number1 = scanner.nextDouble();
         a1[i] = number1;

         System.out.println(
                   "Please enter a double for array2[<" + i + ">] "); 
         double number2 = scanner.nextDouble();
         a2[i] = number2;            
     }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I technically have two parameters? Considering I'm having two arrays created?

Comment: Yes, but in you original `main`, you only have one variable for `mumElements`. I was just giving you an alternative.  But yes, if you want two parameters, you should get to arguments from cammand line, then call you method with two args.  Watch for my edit.

Comment: That helped out a lot! Thanks!

Comment: You don't unaccept an answer just because you run into another problem. An accept means that a specific answer was answered, not that we helped you complete your entire assignment.

Comment: Apart from that. What is your problem?

Comment: Just declare the variable outside the block. See what I did. I fixed that also, which I noticed.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the site =/

Comment: It's ok, just teaching you the ropes. Hope everything works for you now